# Powershell How to Overload Array Index Operator?

Tags: arrays, powershell, class, indexing, overloading

In Powershell, how do you overload the indexing of an array operator?

Here is what I am doing now:

```
class ThreeArray {

    $myArray = @(1, 2, 3)

    [int] getValue ($index) {
        return $this.myArray[$index]
    }

    setValue ($index, $value) {
        $this.myArray[$index] = $value
    }
}

$myThreeArray = New-Object ThreeArray

Write-Host $myThreeArray.getValue(1) # 2

$myThreeArray.setValue(2, 5)
Write-Host $myThreeArray.getValue(2) # 5
```

And, I want to do this:

```
$myThreeArray = New-Object ThreeArray

Write-Host $myThreeArray[1] # 2

$myThreeArray[2] = 5
Write-Host $myThreeArray[2] # 5
```

So, how do I operator overload the indexing of an array?
Is it even possible at all?

Thanks!

Comment: I dont think you can do that. You could do `$myThreeArray.myArray[1]` instead

Comment: Agreed, Write-Host, outside of specific needs should not be used, ... but.... as to the pointer by mklement0, being the go to statement. Jeffrey Snover change his stance on this as of May 2016.
With PowerShell v5 Write-Host no longer "kills puppies". data is captured into info stream ... https://twitter.com/jsnover/status/727902887183966208 .... .... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Write-Information?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: Good point, @postanote; here's my amended comment:

Comment: As an aside: [`Write-Host` is generally the wrong tool to use](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/), unless the intent is to write _to the display only_, thereby bypassing PowerShell's success output stream and thus the ability to send the output to other commands, capture it in a variable or redirect it to a file. That said, in PSv5+ `Write-Host` now writes to the [information stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection), whose output _can_ be captured, but only via `6>`.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest approach is to derive from [`System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.collection-1)

```
class ThreeArray : System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[string]
{
  ThreeArray() : base([System.Collections.Generic.List[string]](1, 2, 3)) {}
}
```

To demonstrate:

```
$myThreeArray = [ThreeArray]::new() # same as: New-Object ThreeArray

$myThreeArray[1]     # print the 2nd element

$myThreeArray[2] = 5 # modify the 3rd element...
$myThreeArray[2]     # and print it

'--- all elements:'
$myThreeArray        # print all elmements
```

The above yields:

```
2
5
--- all elements:
1
2
5
```