# Attempting to override the indexer for Powershell class

Tags: c#, powershell, collections, overriding

I'm attempting to create a Powershell class inheriting

**System.Collections.ICollection**, and I want the indexer to return the elements of an Arraylist object within the class. Example in C#:

```
class ThingCollection : ICollection {
    private ArrayList ArrayOfThings = new ArrayList();
    ThingCollection() {}
    public void Add(Thing myThing) {
        this.Thing.Add(myThing);
    }
    // Below is what I want to implement in PowerShell
    public Thing this[int index] { 
        get {
            return (Thing) this.ArrayOfThings[index];
        }
    }
}
```

Non-working Powershell:

```
Class ThingCollection : System.Collections.ICollection
{
    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$ArrayOfThings = `
        [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
    ThingCollection() {}
    [Void]Add([Thing]$myThing)
    {
        $this.ArrayOfThings.Add($myThing)
    }
    # Below is invalid code
    [Thing]this[[Int32]$index]
    {
        return $this.ArrayOfThings[$index]
    }
}
```

I tried to adapt the answer of an older question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/55435909

by experimenting with iterations along the lines of

```
ThingCollection() : base([System.Collections.Generic.List[]]()) {}
```

e.g.:

```
[Thing]ThingCollection([Int32]$index) : base([System.Collections.Generic.List[Int32]]($index)) {}
```

**Error:  A constructor cannot specify a return type**

etc... but I'm reaching there as I don't really see how that might work.

There is the option of creating a getItem method, however it would be immensely helpful to have a direct implementation of the indexer override.

I sincerely appreciate any help!

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes?view=powershell-5.1) of PowerShell classes, it seems custom indexers are not a supported feature.

But why not make the entire class inherit directly from `ArrayList`?

```bsh
class ThingCollection : System.Collections.ArrayList
{
    ThingCollection() { }
}
```

Usage:

```bsh
# create
$things = New-Object ThingCollection
# or
$things = [ThingCollection]::new()

# store
[void]$things.Add($myThing)

# retrieve
$things[0]

# modify
$things[0] = $myOtherThing
```

Comment: Hi Marsze, I appreciate the idea.  I tried experimenting with using the Arraylist in a few ways, however the issue is that I need the array to be a property of the object, rather than the object itself.   This is because the Arraylist elements are custom error records, and this "ThingCollection" containing the error records is set as a custom property for a System.Data.Common.DbException object.  This is all intended to create a custom database exception that contains highly detailed exception information.

Comment: @Aelinon10 Short answer: Indexing is not possible in PowerShell classes. But you could still write your own .NET type in C# and use that.